# Disable/Close/Quit/Exit Terminal screen from python on Geany (Ubuntu)

Tags: python, ubuntu, terminal, geany

I wrote a program to Open a video in GUI format by Python on Ubuntu and I don't want command terminal screen which always open just after program execution through Geany compiler.

Can you please me to get away from this Terminal screen

```
import Tkinter,ttk 
import tkMessageBox
from Tkinter import *
import io,sys,os,subprocess
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

def askforvideo():
    global process
    name= askopenfilename(title=[("videopen")],filetypes=[("Video Files","*.h264")])
    if name != "":
        subprocess.call(['vlc',name,'--play-and-exit'])
    return

 root = Tk()
 root.title("Flight Recording Application")

 mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="200 200 200 200")
 mainframe.grid()

ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Video Open",    command=askforvideo).grid(column=10, row=3)
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Exit",          command=root.quit).grid(column=95, row=3)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: have you tried root.withdraw() ?

Comment: @Duncan where should I type this line on program?

Comment: @Duncan, that will hide his GUI window, but I think he wants to hide the blank command prompt window that appears when you execute a Python script.

Comment: @Duncan Yes u right... root.withdraw() is disable my GUI screen rather than Terminal screen

Comment: @Fahadkalis, try renaming your python script from `.py` to `.pyw`. On Windows, that keeps the terminal window from appearing. Not sure if it works on other operating systems, though.

Comment: @Kevin But my project is on Ubuntu

Comment: @Kevin aaah ok, i suspect there will be a compile flag that can be set, similar to py2exe's "windows" vs "console" option.

Comment: Ok, its not a compile issue, its the way that Geany executes commands. it uses calls the terminal and then executes the command, you can swap it out for bash instead and it will be fine, just be aware that this change has been made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will work.

Click Edit>Preferences>Tools
In the terminal field change the value to

> bash -x %c

This will execute your python command from bash instead of the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an older version of Geany, it may be worth updating the repository and using the virtual terminal emulator at the bottom.

Comment: I didn't get u... I know about terminal window in Geany but it is the separate Terminal window which open with execution of Program

Comment: Oh I see. If you run through the normal bash terminal it should run fine with no extra terminal appearing. I believe Geany launches a new shell to run a GUI through the VTE

Comment: how do I get that one

Comment: Applications - accessories - terminal. Or depending on your Linux distro, ctr+alt+T usually works